# How can I plot one trend figure with different aes of linetype, shape and color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, geom

I want to observe the trend of FTSW. Colors are distinguished by different blocs, and shapes and line types are distinguished by traitement, like the figure below:
[image]

Please see the original data below:

```
df<-structure(list(Bloc = c(7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 
                            7, 8, 8, 5, 5), Pos_heliaphen = c("W16", "W17", "W36", "W37", 
                                                              "X02", "X03", "W16", "W17", "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03", "W16", 
                                                              "W17", "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03"), traitement = c("WS", "WW", 
                                                                                                                 "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", 
                                                                                                                 "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW"), Variete = c("Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                                            "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                                            "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                                            "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas"), Date_obs = c("D07_27/05/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "D07_27/05/2021", "D07_27/05/2021", "D07_27/05/2021", "D07_27/05/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "D07_27/05/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "D13_08/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", "D13_08/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "D13_08/06/2021"), FTSW_apres_arros = c(-0.82561716279966, -0.83052784248231, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -0.833812425397989, -0.826677385087996, -0.831991201718322, -0.827650244364889, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.900083501645054, 0.899646933005172, 0.920126486265779, 0.901668054319428, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.899616920453791, 0.899570142896103, -0.82561716279966, -0.83052784248231, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -0.833812425397989, -0.826677385087996, -0.831991201718322, -0.827650244364889
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -18L))
```

```
df %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4,5,6) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, FTSW_apres_arros),colour= Bloc,shape=traitement, linetype=traitement) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  labs(y=expression(paste('FTSW')))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

And here is the figure I got:
[image]

If not considering the manual editing, how can I change the legend to the figure belowing:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue with your code is that you put the closing parenthesis for `aes()` at the wrong position so that color, shape and linetype were not included in `aes()`. Also, as your `Date_obs` column is a categorical you have to `group` by e.g. `interaction(Bloc, traitement)` to get a line plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, FTSW_apres_arros, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, 
             linetype = traitement, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**EDIT** You could create a vector of labels from your dataset which you could pass to `scale_color_discrete` like so:

Note: I also added `guide = guide_legend(order = 1)` so that the color legend comes first.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

labels <- df |> 
  select(Bloc, Pos_heliaphen) |> 
  distinct(Bloc, Pos_heliaphen) |> 
  group_by(Bloc) |> 
  summarise(Pos_heliaphen = paste(Pos_heliaphen, collapse = "-")) |> 
  tibble::deframe()

df %>%
  select(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, FTSW_apres_arros, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, linetype = traitement, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = labels, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want! But if I want to present the legend as I updated above, are there any other choices except for manual editing? Thank you! @stefan

Comment: Sure could this be achieved. See my edit for one option.

Comment: Thank you! `|>` doesn't work maybe because I'm still using R.4.0.5, BUT I changeg to to `%>%` . I think it has no big difference for my demand? @stefan

Comment: yep. shouldn't make a difference when switching to the `magrittr` pipe.